# Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/glib/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib - bitlib graphics library ported to c (gtk/cairo)

Tags: c, gtk, cairo, libffi

I'm on `(Darwin Aerosol.local 19.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Tue May 26 20:41:44 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64)` and trying to compile written in `C` test project - bitlib graphics library ported to c (gtk/cairo). from repo: `[https://github.com/bit101/bitlib_c][1]` - I have following problem that `libgobject-2.0.0.dylib` is looking for `libffi.6.dylib` but I have already `libffi.7.dylib`, see below log, how to fix the linking?

```
➜  test git:(master) ✗ make
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/glib/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found
make: *** [default] Abort trap: 6
➜  test git:(master) ✗ /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.7.dylib 
libffi.7.dylib  libffi.a        libffi.dylib@
```